# how to set undefined variable error in js for test cases

Tags: javascript, testcase

```
var editor;
return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      onShow:function(){
           editor=_.clone(ace);
            .................
      }
       enable:function(){
            edit.onPaste = editor.onPaste;
             ..............
      }
}
```

I am new to js
Now i want to write a test case for the function **enable**. here editor is declared as global
and is intialized in **onshow** function. i am getting editor as undefined in the test for enable function, how to resolve this. please help me
Thank you.

The test case is like

```
it('Case #1:Check the enablerule Action function',function(){             
   expect(complexView.enableruleAction(view)).to.equal(undefined);
            });
```

Comment: probably because you are not returning editor's value in onShow function if you only return editor try changing to `onShow: () => editor=_.clone(ace)`

Comment: Is the question "how to __set__ ..." or "how to __fix__ ..."?